# Exterior entry door repair

Tags: repair, wood, exterior, doors, carpentry

I have a 20 year old flat wood entry door (without mouldings or embellishment).  I was going to sand and paint it, but when I sanded, I realized that the wood must have been just a veneer (plywood, perhaps?) since I could pull off pieces, if I'd tried, that would be about 1/4" wide by different lengths.

Is there any way to repair this door, rather than going to the expense of replacing it? The door is perfect on the inside, and I'm sure it's problems on the outside are a result of sun exposure.

Comment: a picture would be great

Answer (score 3):

I agree, it sounds like a veneer that has aged over the years, dried up and is delaminating. One of the problems I see trying to repair the damaged areas with a filler, is that other areas may soon suffer the same problem. With that said, if you want to attempt a fix, you could remove all the loose material, sand off any remaining glue etc , then fill the voids. You could use a plastic wood filler, a thinset type of material or even a setting type drywall compound. Fix it muck like fixing a hole in drywall. spread the filler on with a wide knife, and sand it smooth after it dries.  Be sure to prime and paint the entire surface before allowing it to come in contact with moisture or the outdoor elements.  This may be a semi long term fix, but think you will continue to see problems in the future. Consider a new door soon.